# TypeScript: Generic function return null

Tags: typescript

I am having the next function in typescript:

In c# you have something like **default(T)** but in typescript I dont know.

```
public Base {
...
}


public Get<T extends Base>(cultura: string): T[] 
{

    let res = null;

    try
    {

    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return res;
}
```

I want to return a null but I get an error. If I assign it in a variable the *null* and return the variable happens the same error.

Message is: The 'null' type can not be assigned to the type T[].

The error is:

[image]

How can I do it in TypeScript?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I added the error message

Comment: if I return any, instead of T[], It is working

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have strict null checks on.  This means you cannot assign null to a variable (or return value) unless you’ve said that is a possibility.  So either turn strict null checks off (`strictNullChecks: false` in `tsconfig.json`) or change the return type to `T[] | null`.  Or, better yet, return an empty array and not null.